# How to create virtualenv and include non-global associated installed libraries

Tags: python, virtualenv

Several questions address the way to make a virtualenv that *does* include global site-packages. I'm looking for something different: how to create a new virtualenv based on a Python executable from another location in my network, and also to include the libraries that are installed *in that location in the network.*

I have a local desktop machine, but there is an IT-maintained version of Python and associated installed libraries, and it is the ubiquitous Python used by developers. I'm using virtualenv to create several local versions of Python that allow me to try out libraries or change settings, but I'd also like to maintain an installation that is nothing but a pure mirror of that IT-maintained system.

So the question is how to make a virtualenv that points at that IT-maintained Python, and which *does* reference the previously installed packages *for that Python* and not for my local machine's global site-packages, etc.

Comment: It's a good question - virtualenv incorporates information about the available packages *on creation*, so you can't simply rewrite the path. If all else fails and you control the local machine, you *could* symlink `/usr/lib/pythonX` to the desired location and change it after the creation of the virtualenv...

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely the same thing, but you could try running `pip freeze > requirements.txt` against that version of Python, then using the resulting file inside your virtualenv with `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install copies of the modules there.